# Parse IAM member (`type:email`) using `gcloud`?

Tags: gcloud

I'm stumped trying to parse IAM members using `gcloud` (transforms):

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
--flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
--format="csv[no-heading](bindings.members,bindings.role)"
```

yields:

```
serviceAccount:foo,roles/...
user:bar,roles/...
...
```

Is it possible, using `gcloud`, to extract e.g. the email address from the member property?

Comment: Not an answer - I select JSON for the format and then use `jq` to parse the output. `jq` makes it very easy to extract JSON key/value from the CLI.

Comment: Thanks @john-hanley ... Yes, I like your approach and it's what I prefer to do. It is also more "one thing well". However, it does assume jq and, given that a `gcloud` command can generate `key:value` values, I think `gcloud` should include a way to parse|transform them.

Comment: If you take a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy) for the `get-iam-policy` command you can see that you can't really do that just through the SDK, but you can do it using `jq`, as mentioned by @JohnHanley.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution:

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
--flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
--format="csv[no-heading](bindings.members.split(':').slice(1:),bindings.role)"
```

yields, e.g.:

```
something@service.iam.gserviceaccount.com,roles/editor
someone@gmail.com,roles/owner
```

> **NOTE** the sample approach can be used on `role` too: `bindings.role.split('/').slice(1:)`